# Hive delete element of array

Tags: arrays, hive

How to delete an element of an array?

I have got an array with a different number of elements for each line.
So I would like to delete the last element of each line:

```
array[size(array)]
```

Or filter the `n-1` first elements. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Dhruv looks like he/she tried `array[size(array)]`